# Trying to get a value from an array inside a viewModel( Kendo framework)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

hey i am using kendo framework and i am trying to get specific data from my dataSource inside my viewModel.

i use this code to see inside my view model

```
console.log(viewModel.get("listDataSource"));
```

and now i want to get this value

[image]

i tried

```
viewModel.get("listDataSource")["_data"]["Id"]
```

and some other variations but couldn't get it

Comment: I don't know much but can't we use this


let result =[ ];

 viewModel.get("listDataSource")._data.forEach(function(value) {
    result.push(value);

});

Comment: @SampatAheer normally it would but _data is not function and cant use it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to first call the data() and then the item you want at()

```
viewModel.get("listDataSource").data().at(0).get("Id")
```